# Error while running TensorFlow program premade_estimator.py

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I was running tensorFlow in CPU version and with native pip in Windows. While running TensorFlow for the check "Hello TensorFlow" is output with some warnings. 
on Running `Premade_estimator` I got errors:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a recent version of Tensorflow, it seems that it is not imported correctly.

I faced this error when I was running a script and in the same folder I have downloaded tensorflow, so that when importing "tensorflow" it imports the tensorflow folder where I was located instead of the tensorflow library installed.

Comment: what should I do now?

Comment: Do you have the folder "tensorflow" in that directory? (get_started/)